# Verifying corrupt images with fastAI results in "ValueError: max_workers must be <= 61"

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, fast-ai

I'm running into an error while executing a line in Jupyter (Windows 10, Anaconda env) which should verify scraped images for corruption:

```
Signature: verify_images(fns)
Source:   
def verify_images(fns):
    "Find images in `fns` that can't be opened"
    return L(fns[i] for i,o in enumerate(parallel(verify_image, fns)) if not o)
File:      c:\anaconda\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastai\vision\utils.py
Type:      function
```

When executing the function:

```
failed = verify_images(fns)
failed
```

It returns:

```
C:\anaconda\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastcore\parallel.py in parallel(f=<function verify_image>, items=[Path('bears/black/017e8ca5-161b-42db-b9ee-5f55a...teddy/ff82e6ea-518a-456a-9c08-c1da3e112270.jpg')], n_workers=64, total=None, progress=None, pause=0, method=None, threadpool=False, timeout=None, chunksize=1, *args=(), **kwargs={})
    110         if method: kwpool['mp_context'] = get_context(method)
    111         pool = ProcessPoolExecutor
--> 112     with pool(n_workers, pause=pause, **kwpool) as ex:
        pool = <class 'fastcore.parallel.ProcessPoolExecutor'>
        n_workers = 64
        pause = 0
        kwpool = {}
        ex = undefined
    113         r = ex.map(f,items, *args, timeout=timeout, chunksize=chunksize, **kwargs)
    114         if progress and progress_bar:

C:\anaconda\envs\fastai\lib\site-packages\fastcore\parallel.py in __init__(self=<fastcore.parallel.ProcessPoolExecutor object>, max_workers=64, on_exc=<built-in function print>, pause=0, **kwargs={})
     82         self.not_parallel = max_workers==0
     83         if self.not_parallel: max_workers=1
---> 84         super().__init__(max_workers, **kwargs)
        global super.__init__ = undefined
        max_workers = 64
        kwargs = {}
     85 
     86     def map(self, f, items, *args, timeout=None, chunksize=1, **kwargs):

C:\anaconda\envs\fastai\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py in __init__(self=<fastcore.parallel.ProcessPoolExecutor object>, max_workers=64, mp_context=None, initializer=None, initargs=())
    521                 max_workers > _MAX_WINDOWS_WORKERS):
    522                 raise ValueError(
--> 523                     f"max_workers must be <= {_MAX_WINDOWS_WORKERS}")
    524 
    525             self._max_workers = max_workers

ValueError: max_workers must be <= 61
```

I then tried to limit the max_workers a couple different ways:
`failed = verify_images(fns, n_workers=8)`
`failed = verify_images(fns, max_workers=8)`
and also tried changing `utils.py` & `parallel.py` but it always applies `max_workers=defaults.cpus` resulting in an error.

What is the proper way to limit the number of workers?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. Turns out it isn't a fast.ai codebase that is necessarily breaking it. They by default ask for the number of CPUs that the computer has available. I'm assuming you are also on the threadripper with 64 cores.

The multiprocessing library they are using has a constant set somewhere saying windows machines are limited to 61 cores. Since 64>61... it breaks.

Not sure the best way to fix it. I'll probably end up cloning the repo locally, making the max_workers option available to the verify_images function and then using that. I might do a PR, but I doubt they would accept it.